# Toad for Oracle: using script debugger to debug anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

It simply doesn't work. I cannot set breakpoint and SHIFT + F7 runs to the end.

Is it possible to debug them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is similar to the issue in PL/SQL Developer where a breakpoint can't be set in a test window.  If you dive into DBMS_DEBUG a bit you'll see that to set a breakpoint the caller needs to provide namespace, name (of the program unit), owner, database link (!), and line number.  Thus it appears that code which is not compiled into the database can't have a breakpoint set on it.  My solution is to put the anonymous block I want to debug into a procedure and then call that procedure from the test window.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Another problem. How do you enable debugger on toad? even with your suggestion I cannot solve the problem

Comment: I had to compile with debug after closing and reopening toad